# Get each week number for a ginving month

Tags: sql, t-sql

i'm stuck since two day.
How can I get each week number for a ginving month.

Eg: We got 18, 19, 20, 21, 22 as week for this may.

What I want is a request whitch I could get those week number.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have not provided the table. Below code, I am generating date table and filling date values for May month. I am getting distinct week numbers for the month.

You can easily get weeknumber for anydate using DATEPART(week,). [Read more about DATEPART in msdn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datepart-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

```sql
DECLARE @FromDate DATETIME, @ToDate DATETIME;
SET @FromDate = '2020-05-01';
SET @ToDate = '2020-05-31';
DECLARE @DateTable TABLE(theDate DATE) 

-- all days in that period
INSERT INTO @DateTable 
SELECT TOP (DATEDIFF(DAY, @FromDate, @ToDate)+1) 
  TheDate = CAST(DATEADD(DAY, number, @FromDate) AS DATE)
  FROM [master].dbo.spt_values 
  WHERE [type] = N'P' ORDER BY number;

  SELECT DISTINCT DATEPART(week,thedate) as weeknumbers FROM @DateTable
```

```
+-------------+
| weeknumbers |
+-------------+
|          18 |
|          19 |
|          20 |
|          21 |
|          22 |
|          23 |
+-------------+
```

Comment: Thanks, you got me inspired. I'm using sybase so I don't have much resources.

Comment: Glad that it helped.